# Android SQLite error syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_DATES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_DATES + "TEXT"+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATES_TABLE);
}
```

what wrong with syntax ?

Comment: You should post the error syntax as well

Answer (score 2):

You are missing space between your keywords and values

```
String CREATE_DATES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_DATES + "TEXT"+ ")";
```

should be

```
String CREATE_DATES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_DATES + " TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu are missing a space between the column name and column type, which in your case is TEXT. It should be:

```
String CREATE_DATES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_DATES + " TEXT)";
```

And you may want to use `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(.....` to ensure you don't create the table if it exists(if that is a function you want).